# MacXcode require an entitlement that is not needed

Tags: xcode, macos, provisioning, code-signing-entitlements

We have a Mac App and when we try to build it fails giving the following message
No Matching provisioning profiles found specified features Maps

Their is no use of Maps in the application.  The work around was simply to add map to the profile, which we did, but then Apple rejected the App saying:
This app uses one or more entitlements which do not have matching functionality within the app. Apps should have only the minimum set of entitlements necessary for the app to function properly. Please remove all entitlements that are not needed by your app and submit an updated binary for review, including the following:

com.apple.developer.maps

No idea what to do now- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by creating a custom distribution provisioning profile for the application.